# How to override Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

Tags: magento2

How to override Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

My layout file:

Dckap/Cnet/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">               
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Dckap_Cnet::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</layout>
```

View file:
Dckap/Cnet/view/base/templates/product/product/amount/default.phtml

````
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>
Custom File
<span class="price-container <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
        <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
        <span class="price-label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayLabel() ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>"
        data-price-type="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceType() ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceWrapperCss() ?>"
    ><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?></span>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
        <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode() ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</span>
```
````

Answer (score 1):

I have recently worked on this above requirement.

I will share my suggestion. Please check whether it works for you.

> Vendor/ModuleName/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TM_PlpPrice" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogWidget"/>
            <module name="Magento_Widget"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

And I have written my custom code on

> Vendor/ModuleName/product/price/amount/default.phtml

It works for me.

Comment: Not working.... What did you used it for??? Did you added a session or something?

Comment: I need to customize the PLP page pricing details based on customer group. So I was used this approach. 
No, I didn't add any session.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I wanted to use it for session.

Answer (score 0):

> In module.xml File :-

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Dckap_Cnet" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> In Layout File:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">               
            <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Dckap_Cnet::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Our layout file and above files are same.

Comment: Your just copied from my layout file

Comment: argument name "default"

Comment: After changing your file still now not reflecting

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Got error:  Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'arguments': This element is not expected.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91198/discussion-between-soundararajan-m-and-ronak-rathod).